# Ruby Proc with Parameter

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

I'm trying to send a parameter to a Ruby `proc`

```
p1 = [54, 21, 45, 76, 12, 11, 67, 5]

qualify = proc { |age, other| age > other }

puts p1.select(&qualify(30))
```

This is the error I get:

```
undefined method `qualify' for main:Object
```

**age** comes from the iteration of the `array`, and I want to have that last `parameter` (**30**) to get into the `proc`.

Is a `proc` the right tool to be using for this?  I'm new to proc.  I'm unclear how to get that `parameter` in there.

Comment: What is the desired return value?

Comment: I want to throw in ‘30’ as a variable for a return array with values over 30.  But this is more than just this example.  I’m wanting generalized `procs` that I can throw `params` at.

Comment: Yes.  But I’m trying to implement the `proc` version so I can learn them.

Comment: What are you trying to do here, currying?

Comment: I don't know that term.  I thought throwing a parameter into the proc would be a normal thing.  I'm reviewing the other replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the select statement in the proc itself, so that the proc would calculate and return an array.

```
2.1.5 :119 >   qualify = proc { |age_array, age_limit| age_array.select { |age| age > age_limit } }
 => #<Proc:0xe7bc2cc@(irb):119> 
2.1.5 :120 > 
2.1.5 :121 >   
2.1.5 :122 >   qualify.call(p1, 30)
 => [54, 45, 76, 67]
```

Comment: Excellent.  So you just tossed the array into the proc as a variable itself.  I was stuck on the iterator.

Answer (score 4):

In order to use `qualify` in as `select` predicate, you need to reduce its arity (number of accepted arguments) through partial application. In other words - you need a new proc that would have `other` set to `30`. It can be done with [`Method#curry`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Method.html#method-i-curry), but it requires changing order of parameters:

```
qualify = proc { |other, age| age > other }
qualify.curry.call(30).call(10)
# => false
qualify.curry.call(30).call(40)
#=> true
```

I order to be able to pass this proc to select using `&`, you need to assign it so that it's available in the main object, e.g. by assigning it to an instance variable:

```
@qualify_30 = qualify.curry.call(30)
```

Now you can call:

```
p1.select{ |age| @qualify_30.call(age)  }
# => [54, 45, 76, 67]
```

or:

```
p1.select(&@qualify_30)
# => [54, 45, 76, 67]
```

or inline:

```
p1.select(&qualify.curry.call(30))
# => [54, 45, 76, 67]
```

Comment: At the end you could do `p1.select(&@qualify_30)` or it could be done inline like `p1.select(&qualify.curry.call(30))`

Comment: There's no need to use an instance variable unless this needs to be persisted, and if so, could be a constant instead. You can also use a shorter notation: `@qualify_30[40]` where `[]` is an alias to `call`.

Answer (score 4):

The easy way is to shuffle up how you define this:

```
p1 = [54, 21, 45, 76, 12, 11, 67, 5]

qualify = proc { |age| age > 30 }

puts p1.select(&qualify).join(',')
```

By moving the `30` into the `qualify` proc you've baked in the condition, it's no longer dynamic. Remember, the only methods that can be used with the shorthand `&:` trick are zero-argument ones, or single argument ones with `&` on a proc.

You could also use a *closure* to have the comparison variable exposed:

```
p1 = [54, 21, 45, 76, 12, 11, 67, 5]

required = 30

qualify = proc { |age| age > required }

puts p1.select(&qualify).join(',')

required = 10

puts p1.select(&qualify).join(',')
```

The better way is to just spell it out, that's what Ruby is all about. Here in a more idiomatic form:

```
p1 = [54, 21, 45, 76, 12, 11, 67, 5]

puts p1.select { |age| age > 30 }
```

The only reason for an intermediate Proc is if you'd want to, for some reason, save that somewhere and re-use it later.

Comment: "the only methods that can be used ... are zero-argument ones" - but `qualify` here has arity of 1. And it's not even a method. Perhaps, this assertion can be reworded somehow.

Comment: And methods with params can be used, of course. Because the `&` doesn't see the method call. Only its result. https://repl.it/repls/EuphoricPunctualBetatest

Comment: I see you've taken the required out of the role as `parameter`, so that really is just another hard coded `proc` as I see it.  Doesn't really respect `DRY`.  I assumed it would be easy to throw in the `param`.